# Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

Tags: asp.net, oracle, iis-7, windows-server-2008, gac

I have installed a Web app on IIS 7.0 Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit.
I am referring an oracle.DataAccess.dll;
When I try to access the application I get the following message:
"Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."
Can anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems the Oracle Data Access Component installation process using the "11.2 Release 3 (11.2.0.2.1) with Xcopy Deployment" version is broken. To fix this you must register the missing assemblies in the GAC. To do this for this specific version run these commands from within an administrator console:

```
md C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Oracle.DataAccess\4.112.2.0__89b483f429c47342\

copy %ORACLE_HOME%\odp.net\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Oracle.DataAccess\4.112.2.0__89b483f429c47342\

md C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Oracle.Web\4.112.2.0__89b483f429c47342\

copy %ORACLE_HOME%\asp.net\bin\4\oracle.web.dll C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Oracle.Web\4.112.2.0__89b483f429c47342\
```

Note that this registers only the DLL's but not other languages resources. So, if you are using any another language than English (de, es, fr, it, ja, ko, pt-BR, zh-CHS, and zh-CHT), then you need to register these as well using the corresponding resource file.

If you have Visual Studio installed on the machine, you can issue the following commands instead:

```
gacutil /i %ORACLE_HOME%\odp.net\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
gacutil /i %ORACLE_HOME%\asp.net\bin\4\oracle.web.dll
```

Note: look for gacutil.exe under the Visual Studio installation folder for it.

Hope this helps.

P.S. Or you can try [this](http://rambletech.wordpress.com/2011/09/26/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-oracle-dataaccess-error/).

Comment: The link you posted fixed my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

I avoided registering the 11.2 Release 5 assemblies in the GAC by [setting "Enable 32-bit Applications" for the application pool to true](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/178312/Could-not-load-file-or-assembly-Oracle-DataAccess).

Answer (score 11):

You may need to enable 32-bit applications in your AppPool.

http://www.alexjamesbrown.com/development/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-chilkatdotnet2-or-one-of-its-dependencies-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format/

Comment: Works perfectly for me do it.

Answer (score 5):

You need to register that dll on the live server using GAC util. Also check if its present in bin folder or not. Some times missing dll's in bin directory results in same error

Comment: I would like to mark your answer as useful, but I don't have enough rep. Thank you, anyway.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I use VS 2010, Oracle v11 64 bits. I might to publish in 64 bit mode (Setting to "Any Cpu" mode in Web Project configuration) and I might set IIS on Production Server to 32 Bit compability to false (because the the server is 64 bit and I like to take advantage it).

Then to solve the problem "Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess'" (sometime appear the "Compiler Error Message: CS1705: Assembly" error):

- In the Local PC and Server is installed Oracle v11, 64 Bit.
- In all Local Dev PC I reference to Oracle.DataAccess.dll (C:\app\user\product\11.2.0\client_1\odp.net\bin\4) which is 64 bit.
- In IIS Production Server, I set 32 bit compatibility to False.
- The reference in the web project at System.Web.Mvc.dll was the version v3.0.0.1 in the local PC, however in Production is only
  instaled MVC version 3.0.0.0. So, the fix was locallly work with MVC
  3.0.0.0 and not 3.0.0.1 and publish again on server, and it works.

Answer (score 3):

Installing 64-bit ODAC 11.2 Release 3 (11.2.0.2.1) Xcopy for Windows x64 from:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

Fixed it for me. Make sure to update your system path as per step #4 in the readme file.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer, published by George Netu helped to solve my problem, but I had to fiddle with some additional trifles:

**Problem description:**

Under *C:\Windows\assembly*, I found two *Oracle.DataAccess* items(GAC-folders?). Relict, caused by several Oracle client installations. One item showed Version 2.112.1.0 but was **actually** version 2.121.2.0 (visible through *Properties->Version*). That inconsistency was the bug.

**First unhelpful attempts:**

- tried to deinstall and reinstall the Oracle full client, both in versions Runtime/Administrator
- tried to redeploy the correct .dlls
- tried to copy the new installed assemblies in the GAC serveral times, as stated in the accepted answer above via command prompt (but that didn't solve the version mismatch..)
- tried to use `gacutil /i ...`

**Final success:**

I landed on the [Gacutil.exe msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c(v=vs.110).aspx) and were ultimately able to delete the items from the *C:\Windows\assembly* folder.

```
gacutil /u Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.1.0, Culture="Neutral",PublicKeyToken=45e343aae32233ca
gacutil /u Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.212.2.0, Culture="Neutral",PublicKeyToken=45e343aae3223abc
gacutil /u Oracle.Web, Version=2.112.1.0, Culture="Neutral",PublicKeyToken=45e343aae3223def
```

After that, i repeated the two `gacutil /i ...` commands and the two dlls appeared there in consistent versions.

Finally restarted the IIS, and it works..

Comment: HI i got the same error. I tried everything said here. Still no success. Any suggestion u can give ?

Comment: completely remove all these items from the GAC, redeploy, then check if you have all the same versions in your application, your bin folder, and in GAC!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it is a quite annoying issue I faced sometimes. The main problem is that an web application uses wrongly 32 bit Oracle.DataAccess.dll instead of 64 bit, or in the reverse case. There are a few solutions for it.

**1. Enabling 32-bit applications** in the application pool if your application is 64 bit and need to run 32 bit Oracle.DataAccess.dll.

Go to the IIS and set true for "Enable 32-Bit Applications" option in Advanced Settings of an Application pool.

**2. Correcting reference dll.**

Reference path is supposed to be system reference path configured by Oracle Installation process. But, some cases such as installing or updating new Oracle version, the latest DLLs doesn't update old ones, or path is changed, or a reference is not updated in the web application project. Therefore, we should correct Oracle.DataAccess reference manually.

Go to the web application and remove Oracle.DataAccess reference. And add new reference for Oracle.DataAccess. It must be correct Oracle.DataAccess.dll from your oracle installation path. For example:

C:\Oracle\product\12.2.0\client_1\odp.net\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll

> ODP.NET and Dependent Unmanaged DLL Mismatch
>   To enforce the usage of
>   Oracle.DataAccess.dll assembly with the correct version of its
>   unmanaged DLLs, an exception is raised if Oracle.DataAccess.dll
>   notices it has loaded a mismatched version of a dependent unmanaged
>   DLL.
>
> https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/InstallODP.htm#ODPNT152

**3. Easy and quick way** (but not proper solution) to fix the issue is that override directly an Oracle.DataAccess.dll file copying from oracle installation path (for example: C:\Oracle\product\12.2.0\client_1\odp.net\bin\4\ ) to Bin folder of your web application.

Hope this helps you a little. Good luck.

Comment: Step 2 fixed my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I go to the project properties in general section set platform target to 64 bit (x64) and my problem solved

Answer (score 0):

In application pool ---> click Advance settings --> Enable 32 bit option

see the this image

[image]