# Could not load file or assembly “Oracle.DataAccess” or one of its dependencies

Tags: oracle

I am trying to run this desktop application with oracle database. I keep getting this error

> "Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.2.0, Culture=neutral, or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format".

How can I solve this problem?

FYI: I made the desktop application using .NET with Visual Studio 2015 and an Oracle database.

Comment: "this" application? is it a name of the application?

Comment: I made the desktop application using .Net visual studio 2015 with Oracle Database

Comment: Could you please post the `app.config` in here to indicate the issue? We have no enough information to help you to fix it. But according to the error message, you don't have oracle client or ODAC installed in your PC, or you defined the wrong assembly version in the `app.config`. And also, please refer the similar question: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596834/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-oracle-dataaccess-or-one-of-its-dependencies)